# Iccube: measure as a filter

Tags: dimensions, iccube, iccube-reporting, measures

Iccube - Reporting:
I would like to use certain values of measures as a filter.

For example:
dimension: product -
measure: price

I would like to filter all products which are < 50€.
A workaround would be a second dimension "price" but I dont want that because than the schema will load much longer.

Optional: i can define the price as a custom property of the dimension.

Note: i dont want to use something like this 
([product].CurrentMember.properties("price") = '50') because there are many different values

cheers j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might solve this on the server or in the reporting.

**In the server** :

You can add a utility hierarchy similar to the one described [here](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_ranged.php). As this applies only to one product you would need to do this as a secondary hierarchy of the dimension with the products (you need a new column with this info when loading the dimension).

**In the reporting**.

The filter is missing yet from the data wizard but you might enter an MDX that filters your products. You can do this with the [MDX Filter function](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Filter.php).

The point with this solution is if you query defines a [subselect](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SubQueries.php) or a [where clause](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Where%20Clause.php) and whether you want to use this when filtering your products. Using the query context means that if your query defines a particular filter, e.g. [MyCountryInFilter], it will be used when evaluating the filter measure.

```
Filter( [Products] , [Measures].[MyMeasure] )
```

will evaluate [MyMeasure] as ( [MyMeasures], [MyCountryInFilter] ). You can indeed make this independent from the filter by using

```
Filter( [Products], ( [Country].defaultmember, [MyMeasure] )
```

The more robust version to make this 'filter' independent is by using a static set. If the set is *always* the same you might create a static set (define it in the schema) as described [here](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Create%20(Set).php) :

```
  CREATE STATIC SET [MyFilteredProducts] as Filter( ...
```

it's also possible to define a set evaluated with a static context at request level

```
WITH 
  STATIC SET [MyFilteredProducts] as Filter( ...
...
```

hope it helps